# OpenLayers 6.1.1 Vector Layer Memory Leak

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, openlayers

I'm currently experiencing an issue in my web application where vector layers are being retained in memory when switching away from the map view in the web app.

I currently have 20 vector layers on my map and every time I leave and return to the page it retains those 20 layers and adds on a new set of the layers.

It seems to be a similar issue to the one raised in https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/9556.

This is my code for destroying the layers. Has anyone encountered this issue in version 6 of OpenLayers post beta?

```js
    const layers = this.map.getLayers();
    while (layers.getLength() > 0) {
       const layer = layers.item(0);
       if (layer.get('layerSourceType') === 'VECTOR') {
          layer.getSource().clear();
       }
          layer.getRenderer().dispose();
          layer.setSource(null);
          this.map.removeLayer(layer);
    }
    this.map.setTarget(null);
    this.map = null;
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _everytime I leave and return to the page_? Do you close your browser / the accordant tab or do you navigate within your app?

Comment: Navigate within the app

Comment: Okay. Where do you add your layers to your map, e.g. `ngOnInit`?

Answer (score 0):

That would be hard to give an exact response without the full code or a fiddle to illustrate. However, I got your code, and could assure its removing all the layers.

There are several ways of doing this, and yours is one of them that works.
You could also get a specific layer like this:

```
var layerToRemove = this.map.getLayers().getArray()[0] // or any other layer index
this.map.removeLayer(layerToRemove)
```

But it does the same of your code. You could also store these layers in variables and manage them, which also does the same, like:

```
var layerToRemove = new TileLayer({ source: new TileSource() })
this.map.removeLayer(layerToRemove)
layerToRemove = null
```

But for me, it looks like the problem is not with the layers removal itself, but the way you are creating them or the place you are removing them. Try providing a more complete example next time.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently dealing with this same issue, in 6.1.1 as well.

Using Chrome's Memory Timeline profiler, I can see that in my case, a VectorTileSource is retaining references to VectorTileLayers through a `listeners` array.

As you may know, the VectorTileSource class extends from Source, Object, Observable, and finally EventTarget (where the listeners are). So each VectorTileSource is an EventTarget with methods like `on(evt, listener)`.

When `on` is called, the listener function is stored on the EventTarget instance itself, in order for the instance to call it when the event happens. Since it holds a reference to the listener function, that retains the listener function. And the function retains its *closure scope*, which can hold on to layer internals, and by extension, many other things.

It looks like each VectorTileLayer adds an event listener to its Source, and deregisters it when the source changes. However, if it never changes, the event listener is never deregistered. It stays registered on the Source.

So it seems like `layer.setSource(null)` is the proper fix. This removes the layer's event listener from the source.

Comment: This might not be a complete fix. This helped in my situation, but the memory was still being retained by something else.